# Bash nested autocomplete calling nested functions

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I'm attempting to build a generator for bash completion, but I need to be able to call 'nested' commands. Here is what I have so far.

```
#!bash

_test()
{
  local cur prev

  cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}

  case ${COMP_CWORD} in
    1)
      COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "plain" -- ${cur}))
    ;;
    2)
      case ${prev} in
        plain)
          _plain
        ;;
        show)
          COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "some other args" -- ${cur}))
        ;;
      esac
    ;;
    *)
      COMPREPLY=()
    ;;
  esac
}

_plain() {
  local cur prev

  cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}

echo ${COMP_CWORD}
echo $cur
echo $prev
  case ${COMP_CWORD} in
    2)
      COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "one two three" -- ${cur}))
    ;;
    3)
      case ${prev} in
        one)
          __one
        ;;
      esac
    ;;
    *)
      COMPREPLY=()
    ;;
  esac
}

__one() {
  echo "another"
}

complete -F _test test
```

including debug output. For some reason `COMP_CWORD`, `cur`, and `prev` do not get updated when calling down into the `__one` function. In what way can I accomplish a nested bash completion script like this?

Comment: You can pass the needed info using function's parameters.

Comment: Hi Emily, could you elaborate a little in an answer? then I can mark your answer as correct if it solves my issue.